# Nginx map, regex on URL

Tags: nginx

I have this config to avoid some logging for access_logs:

```
map $request_uri $loggable {
  /myapp/readiness 0;
  [HERE I NEED SOMETHING TO AVOI "socket.io"] 0;
  ^(.*)\/socket.io\/(.*) 0; # Something like this
  default 1;
}

server {

    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main if=$loggable;
```

In the line `[HERE I NEED SOMETHING TO AVOI "socket.io"]` I need a way to set the value `0` to each URL that contains `socket.io`.

I can't do something like this:

```
map $request_uri $loggable {
  /myapp/readiness 0;
  /myapp/my-bff/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OHv2uJ9 0;
  /myapp/another-bff/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=XXXX 0;
  default 1;
}
```

Because each URL that contains `socket.io` has a random hash there.

How can I do a regex or something?

Comment: Sure a map is a great place for a regex. They are evaluated early in the cycle before other locations are, so they do not impact the flow.

Comment: Ok, but I'm confused on how to make the regex under map blocks, I've read is different from location block, I'm not sure how to use the double quote and ^, I'm trying to find some documentation

Comment: See the [map directive documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map). Regular expressions begin with a `~`.